# How to put margins to a imageview in FrameLayout android?

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I have a blue box. The red and the green ones are placed in a linear layout. The Blue Box is in a frameLayout. So i need to align the top of the blue box with the top of the green. How can i do this by making it work for every single screen. Can i even do it ?? Thanx.
    The xml looks like this.

```
<FrameLayout>

     <LinearLayout orientation : vertical>

          <TextView/>  // red slab
          <TextView/>  // green slab

</Linearlayout>
<ImagView/> // blue box
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Question]

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: I think u should put the green one and the blue one in frame layout together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Relative Layout for this and remove the frame layout and linear layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>


      <TextView/>  // red slab
      <TextView layout_below="1st testview"/>  // green slab

      <ImagView align_top="2nd testview" margin_right="25dp"/> // blue box
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanx i got an idea from your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#FA0000" />
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#00FA00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="#0006FA" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```